# Setting up express + react, CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Hey I'm trying to make work my express with react locally. I'm starting react on `localhost:3000` and express on `4040` but somehow my cors doesn't work. I have allowed in my `server.js` all cors stuff:

```
var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000', '*'];
app.use(cors({
    origin: function(origin, callback){
        // allow requests with no origin
        // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
        if(!origin) return callback(null, true);
        if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
            var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin.';
            return callback(new Error(msg), false);
        }
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}));


app.options('/attendant', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.end();
});
```

But still after trying to `fetch` data from express, in my react,I get:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/4040/attendant' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work without the cors options ? By simply having  `app.use(cors())`

Comment: sadly not, still getting this particular error, could it have something with me fetching data by fetch on front or its 100% server issue?

Comment: Ok, it may seem trivial, but since I don't see it in your code : have you required cors ? First by installing it `npm i cors` and then `const cors = require('cors')` before adding it to express ?

Comment: yup i have those, could it be something with wrong ports? I have no idea both apps are set nicely i think

Comment: I'd say this type of response has to do with the server, doesn't depend on the way you request it. I hope I'm not mistaken. Don't think it comes from the ports. You could try changing them to 5000 and 8080 but I think it might end up with the same result

Comment: I've had an idea, check the answer I edited. Hope it'll work

Comment: Don't use the `cors()` middleware **and** your own custom middleware that does the same thing!

Comment: Funny thing, I found the problem after 2nd day, it was ```localhost/4040```....

Answer (score 2):

The order that you apply routes and middleware in matters.

You need to allocate the cors middleware **before** the route that requires it, otherwise it won't be run.

Since the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is reported as missing, you must have assigned them in the other order.

Change the order:

```
app.use(cors()); // No need to use any options. "Everything" is the default, and you included everything in your list.
app.get('/attendant', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By chance I might have spotted an error : your route `'/attendant'` must respond to a GET request. Try this and tell me if it works !

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get('/attendant', function (req, res) {
  res.json({msg: 'It works'})
})

app.listen(4040, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 4040')
})
```

Perhaps if you want to set options to your attendant route, you should use `app.all()`

```js
app.all('/attendant', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next(); // pass control to the next handler
});
```

See these documentations for more : https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html and https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need CORS to communicate with your server. create-react-app has a feature called **proxy**. It allows you to proxy all of your requests to :4040

In `package.json`, add the following entry to the end:

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:4040"
```

Send your requests to your React server on :3000. Example: fetch('/api/example/') and it will work without having any CORS trouble